# Unknown Zelle payment

Tags: fraud, transaction

A Zelle transfer appeared on my bank account that I didn't make. Zelle says to contact my bank for more info on who was paid, but they say money was paid to Zelle!  How do I find out who got my money?!
I am disputing the transaction thru my bank.

Comment: What jurisdiction you're in would be a help.

Comment: What kind of transfer was that? Was it a wire transfer, a direct debit, a cheque or something completely else? And, when asked about the jurisdictin you're in, that is asked in order to be able to help you in a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Zelle is a person-to-person payment service that can be accessed either through online banking or a mobile app. Log in to your bank's web site and see if there is a link for Zelle. The person who got your funds may have left a history there. You should also check for other suspicious transactions and change your password.